# Retrieving data from highly accessed database

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, sqlite, cherrypy

I'm building a web application which, in short terms, allows access to a database to add, search and view the data within.

The problem is in the back end the data requires heavy processing, which can lock the database for around 5 seconds at a time, if the web app tries to access during this time I get a timeout and it fails.

Example:

```
Retrieve_initial_data()
#Step1 processing
Save_step1_results_to_db()
#step2 processing
Save_step2_results_to_db()
....
```

This will carry on until all steps are complete and finally

```
....
mark_initial_data_as_processed()
#End processing
database.commit()
```

I understand that placing a `database.commit()` after each save will free up the database during each processing step, but if this is done and an error occurs, so the program exits, the initial data will be picked up as unprocessed again and attempt to be processed causing integrity errors.

So the question is, what is the most efficient way to solve this problem? To have the heavy processing in the background while still having quick response times from the web application. i.e. Not waiting long times for database to unlock.

I have looked into rollbacks in the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), but they only go back to the last commit()

EDIT: Here is the error code I am getting `OperationalError: database is locked`

Comment: I would switch to MySQL if it's about a highly accessed database. I like SQLite, but in this case it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: As I research more this does seem to be a good idea. Is there much difference between SQLite and MySQL i should look out for when working in python?

Comment: Absolutely not! Both sqlite3 and MySQLdb or pymysql (most common python modules when working with mysql) follows the Python DB-API. So your code will be nearly identical. pymysql is written in pure Python and supports Python 3, while MySQLdb is written in C.

Comment: Are you totally sure that  the db is the one that is blocking the reads?  You are not using sessions?

Comment: No, I'm not using sessions. If I stop the back end processes running the web app works 100%.

Comment: Try running `PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;` after opening the database. This will cause SQLite to use a [write ahead log](http://sqlite.org/wal.html), which will allow readers and a writer to operate at the same time.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back, this does stop the errors. If you put this as an answer I will accept it - nobody else seems to have a solution :)